# Finding Method Definition Within C# Namespace

Tags: c#, class

While I generally work with JavaScript/TypeScript, I am currently combing through some C# code that was written by an outside contractor, to pull some of that code into a new project. Needless to say, I am less familiar with C# than I am with JavaScript.

In one file, which is part of a namespace titled  `RJToGP.Dynamics.GP`, I see this line of code:

```
   return empsheet.SaveEmpsheet();
```

My question is in regards to where to find this method being called here. I cannot find a `saveEmpsheet()` method definition in the `empsheet` file, or on any other file within the `RJToGP.Dynamics.GP` namespace, including in the base class. So my question is, where else would this method be defined?

UPDATE:

I am using Visual Studio, and, to clarify, when I right click and choose "go to implementation" or "go to definition" I get a popup that reads: "Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret." ?? Could this be because this is segmented proprietary code? Just guessing, as usually this would locate the code in question from my understanding.

Comment: in the class definition of the type of `empsheet`. Or in a parent class. (`class A : B` <- B is parent of A). Or in an extension method, somewhere. In VS, right click the method -> Go To definition

Comment: Presumably this C# code is being written/maintained with an IDE of some sort?  Visual Studio is generally the standard example.  If you right-click on the method there should be an option to go to its definition.

Comment: @David, Yes, I tried that with VS. When I right click and choose "go to implementation" or "go to definition" I get a popup that reads: "Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret." ?? Could this be because this is segmented proprietary code? Just guessing.

Comment: @Banon: There could be [a variety of causes](https://www.google.com/search?q=Cannot+navigate+to+the+symbol+under+the+caret+site:stackoverflow.com&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS734US734&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwihnYHPtfrrAhU_hHIEHUBOCZ4QrQIoBHoECAYQBQ&biw=1920&bih=947) for that, in general some problem with the compilation of the code.  Does the code compile in Visual Studio?  Can you delete things like the `bin` and `obj` output folders, any `.vs` or other user-specific folders, leaving only the source code and re-compile?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio;

Just right click the `SaveEmpsheet` and then click the "`Go to Implementation`" from menu :)
The shurtcut is `ctrl + F12` by default

Comment: I had already tried that with VS. When I right click and click on "go to implementation" or "go to definition" I get a popup that reads: "Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret." ??

Comment: so probably the method is under a class library or an referenced assembly that doesn't have symbol. how about go to definition? what about it? try it and tell me what it says. at least it should give you the filename or assembly name of the method

Comment: All right-click options produce the same "Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret" popup message. I am guessing that this may be because this part of the code is segmented somehow because it is proprietary.

Comment: i think your project is not compiling :) i don't think there is such method :)